# How to fetch data from existing table of sql database in android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-listview, android-sqlite, android-arrayadapter

i am developing two android application like APP1 and APP2. and i am entering value in "UserLogin" table from APP1 and i want to fetch data of "UserLogin" table in APP2. but when i am fetching the value it gives me error UserLogin table doesn't exist. how can i fetch data in APP2

here is my database helper class

```
    public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String LOG = "DatabaseHelper";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MessengerDb";

    // Table Names
    private static final String TABLE_USER_LOGIN= "UserLogin";
    private static final String TABLE_CHAT_MESSAGE_THREAD = "ChatMessageThread";
    private static final String TABLE_CHAT_MESSAGE = "ChatMessage";

    //Login table column name
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_LoginUserInfoId = "LoginUSerInfoId";
    private static final String KEY_LoginUserFullName = "LoginUserFullName";
    private static final String KEY_LoginUserAvatarURL = "LoginUserAvatarURL";
    private static final String KEY_LoginStatus = "LoginStatus";


    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        //db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_USER_LOGIN);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.d("Database updated", "Database Updated");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_USER_LOGIN);

        // create new tables
      //  onCreate(db);
    }


    //-----------------Get login user--------------//
    public List<UserLogin> getLoginUser() {

        List<UserLogin> loginUser = new ArrayList<UserLogin>();

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_USER_LOGIN, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                UserLogin uL = new UserLogin();
                uL.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID))));
                uL.setLoginUserInfoId(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_LoginUserInfoId)));
                uL.setLoginUserFullName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_LoginUserFullName)));
                uL.setLoginUserAvatarURL(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_LoginUserAvatarURL)));
                uL.setLoginStatus(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_LoginStatus)));

                // Adding contact to list
                loginUser.add(uL);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return loginUser;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why did you comment this ?
 //db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_USER_LOGIN);

Comment: where creating `TABLE_USER_LOGIN` Table?

Comment: Are APP1 and APP2 two separate apps? That is, each with their own package name and installed separately? If so, you can't just access one app's database from another (imagine the security issues!). You'll have to expose the data in APP2 through a [`ContentProvider`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) to APP1.

Answer (score 0):

This is not right way. Check Content Provider. It is used to access data from database of other application.
[Tutorial of Content Provider](http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/12/content-provider-in-android.html#.VTjDHCGqqko)

Answer (score 0):

First of all **sqllite database are private to particular app**.
so you can not share the sqlitedatabase of one app with another.
So for that android provide **ContentProvider**. it Works with sqllite database.

and in content provider every table is made up with URI so that URI can be shared with another application. and can access the database.

So try ContentProvider.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same database only if you created the running application database in custom content provider.

You cannot directly access the database from running application.

But if you create your running application database in Custom Content Provider then with the help of authorities you can directly access the database.

In this case you don't even need to copy that database.

Refer this [link](https://ashwinrayaprolu.wordpress.com/2011/03/16/custom-content-provider-in-android/) for custom content provider.